# GNU Make: Force use of my own version of a rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this rule in my Makefile:

```
%: ${OBJ}/%.o ${OBJ}/AgentProgram.o ${LIB}
    $(CXX) $^ ${LDFLAGS} ${LIB_DIRS} ${LIBS} $(OUTPUT_OPTION)
```

If obj/Foo.o exists, make will use this rule. However, if the object doesn't already exist, it will use the built-in rule and attempt to directly compile from my .cpp.

Is there some way to define this rule as the default, or turn off the built-in rule?

My workaround is to modify my `make bins` target to produce all .o files first. It wasn't that hard in this case, I altered:

```
bins: ${BINS}
```

and turned it into this: (I already had ${OBJECTS} available)

```
bins: ${OBJECTS} ${BINS}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [cancel pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html), including built-in pattern rules, by defining them without a recipe:

```
%: %.c
%: %.cpp
```

will remove the pattern rule for creating binaries from a `.c` and a `.cpp`.

Or, with a sufficiently new version of GNU make, you can disable ALL builtin rules by adding this to your makefile:

```
MAKEFLAGS += -r
```

(see the manual for the meaning of the `-r` option).

Comment: You can also use a static pattern rule to define your object file rules: this creates an explicit rule which always takes precedence over a implicit rule like a pattern rule.

Comment: Thanks so much. I've been using make for 40 years, and I still learn stuff.